# Why is file_exists() returning false when the file exists?

Tags: php, google-api, xampp

I was trying to use google APIs, and on process, I got an error, saying file is missing.

On trying to access the file, which exits, `file_exists()` returns false, no idea where I'm going wrong.

Note: It is in local host, using Xampp.

The result on execution:
[image]

Image of the directory:[image]

File.php:

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
$dir= __DIR__."\client_secret.json";
if (file_exists($dir)){
echo "exists";
} else {
echo "doesn't exist at ".$dir;
}
?>
```

Please help me find where I have gone wrong.

Comment: where File.php is located

Comment: I'm really not sure if this will work but have you tried to change your "\" to "/". Following the http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php.

Comment: Are you sure you are setting the correct path when you ask for the file?

Comment: Make sure the file has no leading or trailing white space in its name on filesystem, ie. ` client_secret.json `.

Comment: @YogeshPaliyal it's in the same location as client_secret.json.
I did try '/', no changes.

Comment: @PekosoG, I am not very sure.

Comment: @ino Yes, it has no white spaces, still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a dir on that folder from dos and check that your file is not named

> client_secret.json.json

Windows file explorer displays the name of the file without the extension.  There for your file name is client_secret.json with the extension of .json

```
<?php
clearstatcache();
$dir= __DIR__."\client_secret.json.json";
if (file_exists($dir)){
echo "exists";
} else {
echo "doesn't exist at ".$dir;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your File.php and client_secret.json is located in same file It will work.
try this

```
<?php
  clearstatcache();
  $dir= "client_secret.json";
  if (file_exists($dir)){
     echo "exists";
  } else {
     echo "doesn't exist at ".$dir;
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As `client_secret.json` file is in the same path as `file.php`, you can directly do

```
if(file_exists("client_secret.json")){ //file name without whole path
        echo "Exists";
}else{
    echo "Not Found!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the file.php path ? 
`__DIR__`will find the file.php directory ,so you can echo the `$dir` value , and then check the path is ok ?

Comment: It's in the same directory as the client_secret.php. I tried that, the path appears to be correct, but it still says, it doesn't exist.